# Model body won't deform in pose mode

Tags: rigging

Tried following some tutorials about rigging, however, the body doesn't seem to deform in the pose mode..no idea why.
Would appreciate any advice
Model link: https://drive.google.com/drive/u/1/folders/17X0Mek2GHQeFSZGikP83-QJYM_rz9Vjj

Comment: hello, your link asks for an authorization, instead use for example: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: I fixed the folder it should work now

Comment: you need to parent the object to the armature, not the other way around. Your object is very high-poly, I don't think it's a good idea to use a high-poly mesh for animation maybe consider doing a lower poly version, bake all the details of the high-poly if you want to keep them

Comment: I'm not sure about the low poly but I can't pose no matter which I parent to which

Comment: I can't test your object, it's too high-poly for my computer, I hope someone will tell   :(

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Answer (score 2):

Your character has non-manifold geometry and a massive number of vertices.  This is preventing parenting from figuring out how to calculate automatic weights.  When you try, there is an error message.

You are going to have to retopologize the character in order to make it manageable enough for the automatic weight solver, or you're going to have to parent with empty groups and then use weight painting to manually make the connections between parts of the mesh and individual bones.